# Should I wait until I absolutely need the money to draw income from Social Security?

Tags: united-states, retirement-plan, social-security

I started collection at age 62, but could pay it back. Sometimes I think I should put the money into one of my houses while I am able to do the work myself. I could take a loan from a 401k, but paying it back might present an issue.

Comment: if its either SS or a loan - I'd say you already absolutely need the money.

Comment: A loan offers a way to get at savings without paying income taxes and would allow me to deffer social security as long as I borrowed enough to allow me to make monthly payments in addition to the money I actually need

Comment: Starting collecting Social Security at age 62 (the minimum age when you can _choose_ to start collecting benefits) gives you the lowest benefit amount. There _is_ a provision that allows you to return all the benefit collected to SSA (don't remember if interest is to be included in the money returned) and start receiving benefits all over again at a later age with a larger benefit amount. _But,_ you may have paid income tax on the benefits previously and whether you get the tax back or not is yet another can of worms to explore.

Comment: If you are not making a lot of money at present, you might be better off just withdrawing money from the 401k, as it would be taxed at the lowest bracket.  Delaying SS payments up to age 70 gives a guaranteed 7-8% return.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Social Security site](http://www.ssa.gov/oact/quickcalc/early_late.html#calculator),

> In the case of early retirement, a benefit is reduced 5/9 of one
>   percent for each month before normal retirement age, up to 36 months.
>   If the number of months exceeds 36, then the benefit is further
>   reduced 5/12 of one percent per month.

And for a delay past normal retirement age, there's an 8% per year increase in benefit for each year you delay.

I believe the "return it all" option was discontinued.

There's far too little information in your question for anyone to give a comprehensive answer. In general, one needs to look at a number of variables including their taxable income with and without the social security benefit as well as their health to determine the optimal SS start date.